# OpenCV on Raspbery pi error: HIGHGUI ERROR: v4l/v4l2: VIDIOC_CROPCAP

Tags: opencv, raspberry-pi

I have started to work on Rpi. I have worked on opencv on windows and ubuntu. Now I want to do Image porcessing on Rpi. I have installed latest version 2.4.8 on my Rpi. And I am able to open and display an image. However when I am trying to open webcam and display, it gives me error:  HIGHGUI ERROR: v4l/v4l2: VIDIOC_CROPCAP.

Can anyone tell whats the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

I haved the some error when trying to execute a code that does facedetection , i solved it by adding the files needed in my working folder (source folder).
you can show us the code to find out what exactly you need

Answer (score -1):

If you are using prebuilt binaries, they may be built without v4l support. Try to build your own OpenCV with v4l checked. And of course before that install v4l with development files. You can follow [this](http://www.ozbotz.org/opencv-installation/) tutorial with how to install required dependicies explanied.

Comment: I have used the method to install opencv on ubuntu: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/OpenCV

just changed the step 19: according to filesystem of Rpi. And there is v4l flag ON

I can access webcam in my ubuntu installation of opencv.